# Version checking

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have binary file that call “app”, this file must be bind with “config file” to run.

problem is I have 10 different version of “app”, in different path with different “config file”!

This command show version of “app”:

```
root ~: /home/user1/app -version
2.7
```

The only way that i can get path of executable file and related config file is to run below command:

```
root ~: ps aux | grep app
/home/user1/app bind /home/user1/config1
/usr/app bind /home/user5/config2
/tool/app bind /opt/config3
...
```

Now I want to get list of version of each “app” that bind with config files, something like this:

1. config1 2.7
2. config2 4.9
3. config3 1.2

Any idea?

Comment: "The only way"? Absolutely not. `ps` isn't magic -- everything it does your code can do itself (or other software can do as well).

Comment: ...anyhow, the way I'd generally want to approach this is through your process supervision system -- if your Linux distro uses systemd, for example, you can ask *it* which services are supposed to be up, which executables they run, etc. Same for any other process supervision system (runit/upstart/daemontools/etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i think about shellscript , for e.g 1-get list of “app” , 2-get version of each one , 3-print config and put version in front of it.

Comment: There's no value or benefit from having a file involved. Unless you need the ability to seek(), anything that could read from a file can read from a FIFO as well (or a process substitution, or what-have-you). See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), keeping in mind that the technique there works just as well if with `< <(...some-program...)` as with `< some-file`.

Comment: You have a strange `ps aux` output. Mine shows pids too.

Comment: @KamilCuk you right , i just summarize ps output.

Comment: You can parse `ps aux` output. `ps aux | something | grep app | while IFS= read -r app bind config; do printf "%s %s\n" "$(basename "$config")" "$("$app" -version)"; done`

Comment: Please show exact output and wishes, before we are guessing. Can you have both `/usr/app bind /home/user1/config1` and `/usr/app bind /home/user5/config2` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk -bash: read: ‘bind’: not a valid identifier

Comment: @WalterA what do u mean “can you have both”?

Comment: Your `ps aux` example shows different app's and different config files. Is it possible that one app uses different config files and is it possible that one configfile is opened by different app's ?

Comment: @WalterA yes they are completely independent to each other   , different app, different config file